# How to create listview for displaying sender receiver messages using baseadapter?

Tags: android

when we scroll down or up getview problem?
getview not called properly?
at background images are loading from respective url?
layout is different for sender and receiver..

public class NewReadMessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

```
private LayoutInflater vi;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Typeface tf;

private class Image {
    String pic_url = new String();
    Bitmap thumb;
    String messege = new String();
    int id;
    String time = new String();
    String sender_name = new String();
    public boolean sender_user;

}


private Image[] images;
ArrayList<Messages> messages = new ArrayList<Messages>();

private TextView txt_msg;

private TextView txt_name;

private TextView txt_time;
Button btn_loc;
private ImageView img;

 private ArrayList<Messages> mData = new ArrayList<Messages>();
 private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
 private static final int TYPE_RECEIVER = 0;
 private static final int TYPE_SENDER = 1;
public NewReadMessageAdapter(Context context,
        ReadMessagePostParser messageParser, String sender_id,
        String reciever_id) {

    this.context = context;

    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/tahoma.ttf");
    messages = messageParser.getMessages();
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
    images = new Image[messages.size()];
    for (int i = 0, j = messages.size(); i < j; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].messege = messages.get(i).getMessage_text();

        images[i].time = messages.get(i).getTime();
        if (messages.get(i).getMessage_from().equals("YES")) {
            images[i].sender_name = messageParser.sender_name;
            images[i].pic_url = messageParser.sender_pic_url;
            images[i].sender_user = true;
            images[i].id = Integer.parseInt(sender_id);


        } else {
            images[i].sender_user = false;
            images[i].id = Integer.parseInt(reciever_id);
            images[i].sender_name = messageParser.reciever_name;
            images[i].pic_url = messageParser.receiver_pic_url;

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(images[i].pic_url + " " + images[i].sender_name
                + " " + images[i].messege);
    }
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());

}
public void addItem(final Messages item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSeparatorItem(final Messages item) {
    mData.add(item);

    mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override

public int getCount() {

    return mData.size();
}

@Override

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SENDER : TYPE_RECEIVER;
 }

 @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_SENDER:

                    System.out.println("Sender");
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_sender, null);
                    holder.txt_msg = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_msg);
                    holder.txt_name = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
                    holder.txt_time = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
                    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.user_img);
                    holder.btn_loc = (Button) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.btn_loc);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;
                case TYPE_RECEIVER:
                    System.out.println("Receiver");
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_receiver, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.txt_msg = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_msg);
                    holder.txt_name = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
                    holder.txt_time = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
                    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.user_img);
                    holder.btn_loc = (Button) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.btn_loc);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.btn_loc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out
                        .println("-------------- btn_loc ------------------- Sender");
                Developer.callIntent_userlocation(context, "18.50929796 ",
                        "73.79045371");
            }
        });
        holder.txt_name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("----Name----");

            }
        });
        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("----Image----");

            }
        });
        holder.txt_name.setText(mData.get(position).message_from);
        holder.txt_time.setText(mData.get(position).time);
        holder.txt_msg.setText(mData.get(position).message_text);
        if (position != 0) {
            cached = images[position - 1];
            if (cached.sender_user == flag) {
                holder.img.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                holder.txt_name.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
            } else
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(images[position].pic_url.trim()
                        .replace(" ", "%20"), ReadMessageActivityNew.activity,
                        holder.img);
        } else
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(
                    images[position].pic_url.trim().replace(" ", "%20"),
                ReadMessageActivityNew.activity, holder.img);

        return convertView;
    }
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_msg;
    TextView txt_name;
    TextView txt_time;
    ImageView img;
    Button btn_loc;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to reuse convertView only when both the layouts are the same. As the layouts are different here, when you reuse a convertView used by sender for receiver, then the view may not be as expected.